# Little Big Planet PSP vs PS3

Tags: ps3, version-differences, psp, little-big-planet, little-big-planet-psp

Excluding the graphics quality, what are the differences between the PSP and PS3 versions of Little Big Planet?

Comment: I reworded the two questions into one. You can have small differences playing a game using an emulator, but that comes from the emulator side. Apart from adding features, they attempt to replicate the platform as best as possible, so in an ideal situation you will be playing the game exactly as you would on the playstation. I also find sometimes posters can see "emulator" and immediately think illegal. If I've missed the mark, OP, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: as long as user own a PSP and the game too, emulation would not be illegal as far as i know. I haven't yet checked out http://www.ppsspp.org/index.html

Comment: that's exactly right.

Comment: also ppsspp doesn't require any thing from a a PSP because it is a "HLE" emulator. Buying only the game will be enough,

Answer (score 1):

Basically the key difference is the story and having completely different levels. Also the PSP doesn't have multiplayer.